# ros: kinetic: web_video_server

Tags: ros, robotwebtools, video, web, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi my maintainers,
is there a reason why web_video_server is not available at ros-kinetic default distribution ?
I like this nice tool for my robots frontview cam.

Cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245435/ros:-kinetic:-web_video_server/) by [ChriMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/23415/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2016-10-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like it will be released for Kinetic soon. You may be able to help test it. https://github.com/RobotWebTools/web_video_server/issues/29

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0